# How to override shared element smooth transition in activity's on back pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, onbackpressed

I have started a details activity from a list activity and a couple of shared elements have been animated using `ActivityCompat.startActivity()` and obviously when the `onBackPressed()` of the activity is called the smooth transition is reversed.

But here in my case it creates a problem; the details activity utilizes swiping gestures to browse trough the listItems one by one; and when user is about to return, the smooth transition animates the wrong image and title and in the end the actual image and title of that row is replaced which doesn't creates a smooth transition at all.

I'm trying to use a replacement fadeIn\fadeOut animation for activities when the `onBackPressed()` is called if the position differs the original clicked position, but calling `super.onBackPressed()` doesn't do the magic.

here's the method:

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (originalPosition != positionInParentList) {
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the order of statements, Bring the `super.onBackPressed();` above the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (originalPositionInParentList == positionInParentList) {
        return;
    }
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
```